# pandas pivot changes dtype

Tags: python, pandas

After create a new dataframe with pandas pivot_table, the dtype changes from int32 to float

Original dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='columns', dtype='i4')
print(df.head(11))
```

output:

```
         clock   eventid         ns  objectid  value
0   1505960158  62704261  327504323     32219      1
1   1505962773  62711138   22192905     32219      0
2   1505400465  61216428  123915259     32233      1
3   1504642494  59208977  369082011     32254      1
4   1504643325  59210478  576875730     32254      0
5   1504642494  59208978  369082011     32260      1
6   1504643325  59210479  576875730     32260      0
7   1504224224  58101461  445846619     13479      0
8   1504258784  58187457  204908064     13479      1
9   1504310624  58318750  443786274     13479      0
10  1504517992  58886060  746243067     13479      1

print(df.dtypes)
```

output:

```
clock       int32
eventid     int32
ns          int32
objectid    int32
value       int32
dtype: object
```

Whe I use pivot_table

```
p = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index="objectid", columns="value", values="clock", fill_value=0).iloc[:, ::-1]
print(p)
```

output:

```
value              1             0
objectid                          
13479     1505534184  1.505467e+09
13485     1505676014  1.505677e+09
32219     1505960158  1.505963e+09
32233     1505400465  0.000000e+00
32254     1504642494  1.504643e+09
32260     1504642494  1.504643e+09
print(p.dtypes)
```

output:

```
value
1      int64
0    float64
dtype: object
```

Why **0** column become float? How to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sample data may not show it, but the results of your pivot operation possibly contain `NaN`s, which are of `float` type, so the rest of the column is also upcasted to `float` automatically by pandas for efficient computation. Note that the `NaN`s are filled by zeros (`fill_value=0`), so you don't get to see them.

For example, there is no row with `objectid = 32233` and `value = 0`, so that corresponding entry in your pivot result shows up as `NaN`, which then gets filled with `0`.

Now that it's clear why the columns are upcasted, you can reset the datatype using `astype`:

```
p = p.astype(int)
```

Comment: There is no 'NaN'. The df dataframe have 133 rows but the p dataframe have only 6. I will edit my question.

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Do `df.isnull().any()` and please see what that outputs. One of your results has a `0.0000000e+00` so that's kinda indicative.

Comment: df.isnull().any() returns false for all columns

Comment: @JoaoVitorino The NANs do not need to exist in your sample data for them to show up in the pivot results. For example, there is no row with  object id = 32233 and value = 0, so that corresponding entry in your result shows up as NaN, which then gets filled with 0. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It is odd that Pandas seems to upcast to float even when the original datatype is pandas own Int32 (not NumPy's int32), which *can* contain NaNs