# How to preserve NaN instead of filling with zeros in pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the table that I am trying to pivot:

```
data = [[1,1,"red", 59, np.nan],[1,1,"blue", "yes", np.nan],[1,2,"red", 

8.6, np.nan],[1,2,"blue", "other", np.nan],
[2,1,"red", 61.1, np.nan], [2,1,"blue", "response", np.nan],[2,2,"red", 60, np.nan],[2,2,"blue", 63, np.nan],
[3,1,"red", np.nan, 2],[3,1,"blue", np.nan, 2],[3,2,"red", np.nan,2],[3,2,"blue", np.nan,2],
[4,1,"red", 0, np.nan],[4,1,"blue", 0, np.nan],[4,2,"red", 0,np.nan],[4,2,"blue", 0,np.nan],
[5,1,"red", 88, np.nan],[5,1,"blue", "texas", np.nan],[5,2,"red",61, np.nan],[5, 2,"blue",5.5, np.nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Test', "Question","Quality",'Answer', 'repeat_tag'])
```

Pivoting the table using the following code:

```
pivoted= pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Test","Question"],values =["Answer"], columns=["Quality"],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

When I pivot a table that contains NaN values, some of my columns remain correctly filled with NaN, while others fill with zeros. Because my data contains some values that really are supposed to be zero, I need to retain them and would like to keep the NaN values in the pivoted table where they exist in the table before I pivoted it.

I have read from another question, ([pandas pivot changes dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859400/pandas-pivot-changes-dtype)) that:

"Your sample data may not show it, but the results of your pivot operation possibly contain NaNs, which are of float type, so the rest of the column is also upcasted to float automatically by pandas for efficient computation. Note that the NaNs are filled by zeros (`fill_value=0`), so you don't get to see them."

How do I get around this?

Comment: Will you provide some sample data please? If there is only 1 nan, it is ignored, but if every row for that group is NaN, the output is also NaN?

Comment: Ok, I have added some data-- I should add though that some of the Answer data in my original file are in the form of strings also.

Comment: I don't think you need pivot_table here. Try this: `df.set_index(['Test','Question', 'Quality'])['Answer'].unstack(-1)`